# My c program suddenly came up with an error in the terminal

Tags: c

I was practicing in C when suddenly the terminal came up with this

```
cannot open output file index.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know how this happened

Comment: We also don't know. You have to share more details about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your program (index.exe) is probably still running.  Make sure you terminate all instances of it and try again.  You might have to use the process manager of your operating system.  If you have trouble with that, try rebooting, and then be careful to always terminate the program carefully when you are done running it.